# how to link 3 tables in quarkus?

Tags: quarkus-panache

I m new on framework quakus. I know how to do it with SQL, but no in quakus...
Can you say me the best way/practice for have a json format with 3 tables

client-- commands-- articles
When i get a client how to have for one client, all commands ans all articles by commands.
I do that with the 2 first table

```
Client
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
public List<ClientCmd> clientCmdList;
```

Its ok, but how can i link the tbale article in client (no relation beetwen client and article).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will serve to another beginner

I do

```
@OneToMany(mapped = "client")
public List<Clientcmd> clientCmdList;
in client

@OneToMany(mapped = "commande")
public List<Commandeart> commandeArtist;
in commande
```

When i do a
`getByClient`

The system retreive to me all the commands and articles for a client.

Thierry